# Can't get multiple many to many relationships within the same entity to populate constructor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am making a beer reviews web application and I have one of my many to many relationships working and I would like to make the other relationship from one to many to many to many. when I try to format style the same as brewery I see that I am not allowed to have two of the same arrays.asList in the constructor. this is the code that i currently have that's working.

**Code:**

```
@ManyToOne
private Style style;

@ManyToMany
private Set<Brewery> breweries;

public Review(String beerName, String beerReview, Style style, Brewery... brewery) {
        this.beerName = beerName;
        this.beerReview = beerReview;
        this.style = style;
        this.breweries = new HashSet<Brewery>(Arrays.asList(brewery));
    }
```

Comment: What you cant is have two varargs parameters, theres only one and always at the end of the parameters, accept a List or Set before the varargs brewery

Comment: That has absolutely nothing to do with the JPA API. It is Java